# Sending a Post request with net/http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post, net-http

I need to send data in JSON to another app which runs on the same computer.
I send request like so (rails 3.2.13 )

```
 data = { //some data hash }
 url = URI.parse('http://localhost:6379/api/plans')
  resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, data.to_JSON )
  p resp
  p data
  { resp: resp, data: data.to_JSON }
```

But i get `Net::HTTPBadResponse (wrong status line: "-ERR unknown command 'POST'"):`
How can i solve this problem?

**Update 1**
Updated my code as @Raja-d suggested

```
  url = URI.parse('http://localhost:6379/v1/sessions')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, data)
  p resp
  p data
```

But i still get error  `Net::HTTPBadResponse (wrong status line: "-ERR unknown command 'POST'"):`

Comment: Please look into this http://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/how-to-fix-nethttpbadresponse-wrong-status-line-in-ruby/

Comment: Are you able to post to that url using curl or an external tool like PostMan in Chrome?

Comment: I didn't try that postman. this app is not under my control,

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I don't know what your problem is but what about something like this

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
request.body = data.to_json

response = http.request(request)
```

Comment: why not `http.post(..` call directly ? :) this [method](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post)

Comment: How to add post parameters to http.post?

Comment: @NathanB in know this is coming 3+ years too late, but just in case others have the same question, the params are passed into the data variable. data = {"whatever": array_or_hash, "password_param": "password"} then on the target site, you can call params["whatever"] or params["password_param"] to access the  data sent.