# Forward a response from 3rd party application in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, response, forward

I'm building a web app that needs to login to a 3rd party application and then forward the response back to the browser, so it acts like a proxy. We need this because the user must be logged in automatically in both the other app and in our app. Right now I can send the post request to the other app and I have the response, but couldn't figure out how to forward it back to the browser. From what I know, Rails is using `render` to build the `response` object automatically.

```
 def auth_test
    uri = URI 'login_url'

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    resp = http.post(uri.path, params.to_s)

    logger.info 'Code = ' + resp.code
    logger.info 'Message = ' + resp.message
    resp.each {|key, val| logger.info key + ' = ' + val}
    logger.info "------------------"
    logger.info resp.body

    # if login successful -> login to our app

    # ??? send the response back to the browser (resp) ???

end
```

Appreciate any help/suggestions.

EDIT

```
 def auth_test
    uri = URI 'login_url'

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    response = http.post(uri.path, params.to_s)

    logger.info 'Code = ' + response.code
    logger.info 'Message = ' + response.message
    response.each {|key, val| logger.info key + ' = ' + val}
    logger.info "------------------"
    logger.info response.body

    # if login successful -> login to our app

    # ??? send the response back to the browser (resp) ???
    render response
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at question re [POST-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163507/sending-a-post-request-with-net-http) and relevant [post](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) via `Net::HTTP`. If you don't use json, just adjust it correspondingly. Then add

```
render inline: response.body.html_safe, layout: false
```

- `inline:` means you don't need view (template) for `controller#auth_test` action
- `html_safe` tells Rails that your HTML is safe to generate. By default
  Rails convert any HTML into string to prevent dumb execution of
  malicious code.
- `layout: false` says to render don't use any layout, like 'layouts/application.html.erb' etc.

If needed, you can pass response to View via plain instance variable.

`render response` is not working, bc Rails try to find associated route for this object in accordance with [Rails conventions for render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#wrapping-it-up) and definitely fails, while it's not ActiveRecord/ActiveModel object.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. After editing the source as above the following error occurs: '#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: UPDated answer with appropriate use of `render`